# I am trying to access the GDrive api after authentication with passport js. However, I am getting this error -

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, passport.js, access-token

Error -
The API returned an error: Error: No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set.

What I am trying to do is -

```
app.get("/getinfo", (req,resp)=>{
        const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(myClientID, myClientSecret, redirectURL )
        var data="";
        fs.readFile("token.json", function(err, dat) {
            if (err) throw err;
             data=JSON.parse(dat);
            oauth2Client.setCredentials({
                'access_token': data.token
            });
        });
         listFiles(oauth2Client);
         resp.send("Getting drive files");
     });
```

Where "token.json" consists of the auth token received upon successful validation via passport js. The "listFiles" function is -

```
function listFiles(auth) {
     console.log(auth);
     const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
     drive.files.list({
       pageSize: 10,
       fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
     }, (err, res) => {
         console.log("inside drive api call");
       if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
       const files = res.data.files;
       if (files.length) {
         console.log('Files:');
         files.map((file) => {
           console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
         });
       } else {
         console.log('No files found.');
       }
     });
   }
```

Can somebody help me out on how to make this function work. My objective is to read the list of files of a person's Drive after successful authentication. I have checked my scopes too required for validation.

Answer (score 0):

The callback passed to `fs.readFile` is executed after call to `listFiles`, therefore you are passing `oauth2Client` without access token being set.

You have at least the following options to fix it:

- Call `listFiles` inside the `readFile` callback (after `setCredentials`)
- Replace `fs.readFile` with `fs.readFileSync` so you don't need a callback
- Use `fs/promises` and async/await instead of callbacks